# SQL find characters different in two fields

Tags: sql, t-sql, compare

I have a table with two fields: firstnamedb1 and firstnamedb2

I need to get those that doesnt match but also want to know how many characters are different.

For example, if I have:

```
firstnamedb1        firstnamedb2
RICHARD             RICHRAD
```

Then I know that is a NO MATCH result but also I know that only 2 characters are different.

That way I would know that "maybe" that NO MATCH result was a misstype error and can be fixed manually very easy.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't think of a solution that won't be extraordinarily tedious to implement. Add this to the fact that there's a lot of western names that differ by only one letter (Jay-Jan, Alex-Alec, Simon-Simone) and I can't help but question your approach. For all the effort you'll go to counting how many letters differ (and handling names of differing lengths), you might want to make something coarser and perform the rest on sight. Paul and Paula may be happily married (or whatever relationship you're representing) and Paula is clinically depressed because people keep changing her name to Paul.

Answer (score 0):

```
select firstnamedb1, firstnamedb2, dbo.numdiffchars(firstnamedb1, firstnamedb2)
from yourTable
where firstnamedb1 <> firstnamedb2


create function dbo.numdiffchars(@n1 varchar(60), @n2 varchar(60))
returns int
as begin
  declare @baselen int,
          @extension int,
          @xpos int,
          @numdiff int;
  if len(@n1) <= len(@n2) select @baselen = len(@n1)
  else select @baselen = len(@n2)

  if len(@n1) < @baselen select @extension = (@baselen - len(@n1))
  else if len(@n2) < @baselen select @extension = (@baselen - len(@n2))

  select @xpos = 0, @numdiff = 0;
  while @xpos < @baselen begin
    select @xpos = @xpos + 1
    if substring(@n1, @xpos, 1) <> substring(@n2, @xpos, 1)
      select @numdiff = @numdiff + 1
  end

  return @numdiff + @extension
end
```

If this solves your problem please mark as answer.

Comment: Im running it but I get NULL, any clue? Thanks a lot

Comment: The only thing that springs to mind is whether one of the names being compared is null; I havent built the function to accommodate this, but if this is the case, change the select statement to be:   select firstnamedb1, firstnamedb2, dbo.numdiffchars(isnull(firstnamedb1, ''), isnull(firstnamedb2, '')) from yourTable where isnull(firstnamedb1, '') <> isnull(firstnamedb2, '')